# Why can't I access the middle of the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

I'm working through [this tutorial](https://github.com/gamagori/os-tutorial/blob/master/04-bootsector-stack/boot_sect_stack.asm) - the section I'm on has the bootloader accessing the stack. I'm trying to understand this code:

```
mov ah, 0x0e     ; int 0x10 writes to tty
mov bp, 0x8000   ; set the base of our stack
mov sp, bp       ; there's nothing in the stack, so the base pointer
                 ; and the stack pointer are the same. 

push 'A'        
push 'B'
push 'C'         ; bp at 0x8000, sp at 0x7ffe. 

mov al, [0x7ffe]
int 0x10         ; this prints what's at the top of the stack, 'A'

mov al, [0x7fff]
int 0x10         ; this prints garbage or nothing, for some reason, but
                 ; I would expect it to print 'B'
```

```

I know I'm expected to interact with the stack through `push` and `pop`. But, if I can access the top of the stack directly, why can't I access the middle or the bottom? Is the CPU or the MMU enforcing access restrictions this early in the boot process?

If it helps, I'm testing this code by:

```
nasm -f bin 'this_code.asm' -o boot.bin
qemu-system-x86_64 --nographic boot.bin
```

Comment: You can access it but in 16 bit mode the stack is 16 bit (2 bytes per item). Your observations seem off. `sp` is most certainly not `0x7ffe` It should be `0x7ffa`. Note that `A` is not the top of stack, that would be `C`. So you **are** printing from the middle (actually the bottom) of the stack. `B` is at `0x7ffc`.

Comment: You _can_ access the middle and the bottom. `0x7FFE` addresses the first 16-bit word pushed to the stack (`A`). You can also address `B` and `C` at `0x7FFC` and `0x7FFA`, respectively. That the supposed "BYTE" PUSHes are instead 16-bit WORDs can be derived from the opposite instruction `POP BX` further below in the example.

Comment: @Jester, zx485 that's the ticket - I wasn't counting correctly, and I wasn't envisioning the stack correctly. The tutorial has a bit about 'you can only access the stack top', but it's definitely wrong on that count. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: "stack" is ordinary computer memory.... all the "magic" which makes it called "stack" is the memory address stored in `ss:sp` pair of registers (in 16b real mode), which is used implicitly by instructions like `push, pop, call, ret, enter, leave, int, ...` and some special quirks like `mov ss,ax` disabling interrupts until next instruction (which is expected to be `mov sp,<offset part of new stack address>`), so the interrupt will never happen half-way into the setup of stack address, etc... So as long as you address the same area of memory, you can work with "stack" by ordinary instructions.

Comment: there's actually one more "quirk" which is not obvious, in 16b real mode the interrupts are using the same stack area, as user code, and the interrupts happen quite often (at least 18.2 times per second the BIOS timer interrupt, and keyboard handler also does occur when you are pressing/releasing keys), so if you will try to write some values right below current `ss:sp` memory address, they will get destroyed within next few milliseconds (55ms at most). If you want to use "stack" memory for "local variables", you must thus "reserve" memory by doing something like `sub sp,400` -> 400B reserved.